# Sentences Recognition Using CMU Sphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, sphinx4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVcqh.png)I am a researcher, and I am making speech recognition system using CMU Sphinx. I have succesfully trained words of Sindhi Language with very low accuracy. Now I wanted to train complete sentences. I was Wondering **how to train complete sentences, how to make dictionary, transcript, fileids and other files for complete sentences training**. Help will be highly appreciated.

I Have trained words of Sindhi Language Using CMU Sphinx

Comment: Training for sentences is not different from training for words. I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I added a picture, Kindly review it. It states the error

Comment: Can you give me your email? I can share my previous working words recognition and recent sentences recognition work.

Comment: You should edit your question to properly explain a problem first. Using images instead of text is not a great idea. The better you write the question the faster you get a solution